# INI sections aquivalent to Enum

Tags: c#, enums, ini

I would like to insert an INI file sections as Enum values.

I understand that is the way to get the INI sections:

```
List<string> categories = GetCategories(iniFile);
foreach (string category in categories)
```

How can I insert it to Enum?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, you can't. Rather use a `Dictionary` and store section names as keys.

Comment: @AndreiV I would like the user could change an enum values. He cannot access the code, but ini file sections could be edited and read in code.

Comment: If you read carefully the first line from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) you will encounter the word `constant`. That's what enums are. This means that the user cannot change the values. Enums cannot be constructed dynamically (it _might_ be possible using reflection, but you don't want to follow that path). Please try to provide a concrete example of what you try to achieve. Someone might have a proper solution.

Comment: I believe you can compile any code by using codedom (including the one what is building `enum`s). The questions is: why do you need it? Perhaps you tell us what you want to achieve and there is another, much simpler solution exists?

Comment: @AndreiV Thanks. Could you please guide me a little more about the `Dictionary` suggestion?

Comment: @Sinatr, I would like the user could change an enum values. He cannot access the code, but ini file sections could be edited and read in code.

Comment: Could you provide an example in the question? How would user know valid values from specific `enum` or how would your software use *created by user values* (still a question what exactly you want)? Have you considered instead of editing ini-file provide a UI (aka configuration window)?

Comment: @Sinatr, Thanks. I do not want to ask the user for the values in each execution of the software. If he would like to change the default values he might have the option to access the INI. But I'm really not stuck on the INI idea. If you have a better one- you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum` values are constants and cannot (easily) be modified. Instead, you could use a `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> iniSections = Dictionary<string, string>();
List<string> categories = GetCategories(iniFile);

foreach (string category in categories)
{
     iniSections.Add(categoryName, category);
}
```

You need, of course, to provide a valid `categoryName` for each available `category`.